# Add a Key Event Listener to a programmatically generated MessageBox using ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building an ExtJS4 web application and there's a part there where I show a confirmation dialog to a user to confirm if the user wants to push through with the action. I use a programmatically generated MessageBox to ask the user and the user can click Yes or No.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
    title: alertHeader,
    msg: alertMessage,
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
    cls: 'msgbox',
    fn: function(btn){
        //if user clicks yes, ask for override button
        console.log('btn value = ' + btn);
        if(btn ==='yes'){
        //more code here
        }
});
```

This works as intended, the program follows through with the appropriate actions based on the user selection (Yes or No). However, I want to add functionality wherein the user can simply press Y or N in the keyboard and the program will still execute as if Yes or No was actually pressed in the dialog.

However, I don't know how to go about adding a KeyEvent Listener to a MessageBox and the documentation is of little help.

Comment: Are you bound to Y/N as key events? Because Space/Tab+Space are already available out of the box.

Comment: Well it wouldn't make sense if it's not Y/N for Yes and No right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Ext.util.KeyMap](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap) (and [Ext.EventObject](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.EventObject) for key constants), also we have to set focus on our window to listen keyup events on it.

I create simple fiddle to illustrate how it works - [Key map with message window](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13n5).

Its not complete solution, but I guess rest you can do on your own.
As simple example you can do your logic directly on keypress and destroy `myConfWindow` or `myConfWindow.down()` to certain button and "click" it. But I guess that you want to use this message box in multiple places in your app, so its better to extend `Ext.MessageWindow` and add keymap there.

Comment: It seems that I have to replicate the callback function in the event key code blocks. I'm not sure how I can extend the MessageWindow event though.

Comment: Works as intended. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Attach this getKeyMapForKeyPressSubmit() method to your message box

```
'afterrender' : function() {
   var map = this.getKeyMapForKeyPressSubmit();
}
```

And Method

```
getKeyMapForKeyPressSubmit : function (target, scope) {
var me = this;
return new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target : target,
    binding : [{
            key : 89, //Key for Y button - Ext.EventObject.Y
            fn : function (key, e) {
                //your logic for Yes button
            }
        }, {
            key : 78, //Key for N button - Ext.EventObject.N
            fn : function (key, e) {
                //your logic for NO button
            }
        }
    ],
    scope : scope
});
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a key map of MessageBox through `getKeyMap`. Add a new key listener to it in `afterrender` listener.

```
var myMsg = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            this.getKeyMap().on(Ext.event.Event.Y, function() {
                console.log("Yes");
            }, this);
            this.getKeyMap().on(Ext.event.Event.N, function() {
                console.log("No");
            }, this);
        }
    }
}).show({
    title: 'Custom MessageBox Instance',
    message: 'I can exist along with Ext.Msg'
});
```